# Mongodb responding only after connectTimeoutMS

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

We have 3 web servers load balanced using HAproxy. Out of these 3, 2 are responding to any MongoDB queries as soon as possible but on the 3rd web server, it takes time up to the configured connectTimeoutMS (which is 10 seconds in our case).
This happened all of sudden on this server. Before it was also working as normal as the other 2 web servers. We tried our best to check logs and everything but could not find the reason behind this. What could be the reason?

Comment: This is going to be a very difficult question to answer with just a few sentences describing the general behavior that you are observing. Did you find any connection timeout messages in the application log file on the impacted server? Is the MongoDB cluster a replica set? Did anything change with it recently (change of `PRIMARY` or something)? Can you connect to all members of the replica set from all of the application servers?  We'd like to help but I'm not sure that we are going to be able to without _something_ more concrete like an error message

Comment: We are not getting any error message in any log (eg mongo log). 

Did anything change with it recently (change of PRIMARY or something)? - Nothing chnages.

Can you connect to all members of the replica set from all of the application servers?- Yes

PS: Also, one important thing to note is that: We are able to get responses from nodejs or python script but not from the PHP script. Looks like the PHP extension, mongodb.so has problem. But what problem it can have, we don't know.

Comment: What version of the PHP driver?